# How to use trace in this Racket code?

Tags: nlp, lisp, racket, trace

I am working in a NLP project with Racket.

This code works fine. However, I wish I could trace it.

I am having problems to trace the behavior of the  generate-next function.

That's my code:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/trace)

(require rackunit)

(define english-1
  '((Initial (1))
    (Final (9))
    (From 1 to 1 by NP)
    (From 1 to 2 by DET)
    (From 1 to 3 by NP)
    (From 2 to 3 by N)
    (From 3 to 4 by BV)
    (From 4 to 5 by ADV)
    (From 4 to 5 by |#|)
    (From 5 to 6 by DET)
    (From 5 to 7 by DET)
    (From 5 to 8 by |#|)
    (From 6 to 7 by ADJ)    
    (From 6 to 6 by MOD)
    (From 7 to 9 by N)
    (From 8 to 8 by MOD)
    (From 8 to 9 by ADJ)
    (From 9 to 4 by CNJ)
    (From 9 to 1 by CNJ)
    (From 9 to 2 by CNJ)
    (From 9 to 3 by CNJ)
    (From 9 to 6 by CNJ)))

(define (getf x y)
  (if (eq? (car x) y)
      (cadr x)
      (getf (cdr x) y)))

(define (initial-nodes network)
  (list-ref (assoc 'Initial network) 1))

(define (final-nodes network)
  (list-ref  (assoc 'Final network) 1))

(define (transitions network)
  (filter (lambda (x) (eq? (car x) 'From)) network))

(define (trans-node transition)
  (getf transition 'From))

(define(trans-newnode transition)
  (getf transition 'to))

(define (trans-label transition)
  (getf transition 'by))

(define abbreviations
  '((NP kim sandy lee)
    (DET a the her)
    (N consumer man woman)
    (BV is was)
    (CNJ and or)
    (ADJ happy stupid)
    (MOD very)
  (ADV often always sometimes)))

(define (recognize network tape)
  ;; returns t if sucessfully recognizes tape - nil otherwise
  (call/cc (lambda (return)
             (define (recognize-next node tape network)
               (if (null? tape)
                   (if (member node (final-nodes network))
                       (return #t)
                       (return '())); success
                   (for ([transition (transitions network)])
                           ;; try each transition of the network
                           (when (equal? node (trans-node transition)) ; if it starts at the right node
                               (for ([newtape (recognize-move (trans-label transition) tape)])
                                       ;; try each possible new value of tape
                                 (recognize-next (trans-newnode transition) newtape network)))))(trace recognize-next))
             (for ([initialnode (initial-nodes network)])
               (recognize-next initialnode tape network))
             null))) ; failed to recognize

(define (recognize-move label tape)
  (if (or (eq? label (car tape))
          (member (car tape) (or (assoc label abbreviations) '())))
      (list (cdr tape))
      (if (eq? label '|#|)
          (list tape)
          null)))
```

When I call:

```
(recognize english-1 '(sandy is a happy woman))
```

Trace works fine and I have the expected output:

```
>(recognize-next
  3
  '(is a happy woman)
  '((Initial (1))
    (Final (9))
    (From 1 to 1 by NP)
    (From 1 to 2 by DET)
    (From 1 to 3 by NP)
    (From 2 to 3 by N)
    (From 3 to 4 by BV)
    (From 4 to 5 by ADV)
    (From 4 to 5 by |#|)
    (From 5 to 6 by DET)
    (From 5 to 7 by DET)
    (From 5 to 8 by |#|)
    (From 6 to 7 by ADJ)
    (From 6 to 6 by MOD)
    (From 7 to 9 by N)
    (From 8 to 8 by MOD)
    (From 8 to 9 by ADJ)
    (From 9 to 4 by CNJ)
    (From 9 to 1 by CNJ)
    (From 9 to 2 by CNJ)
    (From 9 to 3 by CNJ)
    (From 9 to 6 by CNJ)))
> (recognize-next
   4
   '(a happy woman)
   '((Initial (1))
     (Final (9))
     (From 1 to 1 by NP)
     (From 1 to 2 by DET)
     (From 1 to 3 by NP)
     (From 2 to 3 by N)
     (From 3 to 4 by BV)
     (From 4 to 5 by ADV)
     (From 4 to 5 by |#|)
     (From 5 to 6 by DET)
     (From 5 to 7 by DET)
     (From 5 to 8 by |#|)
     (From 6 to 7 by ADJ)
     (From 6 to 6 by MOD)
     (From 7 to 9 by N)
     (From 8 to 8 by MOD)
     (From 8 to 9 by ADJ)
     (From 9 to 4 by CNJ)
     (From 9 to 1 by CNJ)
     (From 9 to 2 by CNJ)
     (From 9 to 3 by CNJ)
     (From 9 to 6 by CNJ)))
> >(recognize-next
    5
    '(a happy woman)
    '((Initial (1))
      (Final (9))
      (From 1 to 1 by NP)
      (From 1 to 2 by DET)
      (From 1 to 3 by NP)
      (From 2 to 3 by N)
      (From 3 to 4 by BV)
      (From 4 to 5 by ADV)
      (From 4 to 5 by |#|)
      (From 5 to 6 by DET)
      (From 5 to 7 by DET)
      (From 5 to 8 by |#|)
      (From 6 to 7 by ADJ)
      (From 6 to 6 by MOD)
      (From 7 to 9 by N)
      (From 8 to 8 by MOD)
      (From 8 to 9 by ADJ)
      (From 9 to 4 by CNJ)
      (From 9 to 1 by CNJ)
      (From 9 to 2 by CNJ)
      (From 9 to 3 by CNJ)
      (From 9 to 6 by CNJ)))
> > (recognize-next
     6
     '(happy woman)
     '((Initial (1))
       (Final (9))
       (From 1 to 1 by NP)
       (From 1 to 2 by DET)
       (From 1 to 3 by NP)
       (From 2 to 3 by N)
       (From 3 to 4 by BV)
       (From 4 to 5 by ADV)
       (From 4 to 5 by |#|)
       (From 5 to 6 by DET)
       (From 5 to 7 by DET)
       (From 5 to 8 by |#|)
       (From 6 to 7 by ADJ)
       (From 6 to 6 by MOD)
       (From 7 to 9 by N)
       (From 8 to 8 by MOD)
       (From 8 to 9 by ADJ)
       (From 9 to 4 by CNJ)
       (From 9 to 1 by CNJ)
       (From 9 to 2 by CNJ)
       (From 9 to 3 by CNJ)
       (From 9 to 6 by CNJ)))
> > >(recognize-next
      7
      '(woman)
      '((Initial (1))
        (Final (9))
        (From 1 to 1 by NP)
        (From 1 to 2 by DET)
        (From 1 to 3 by NP)
        (From 2 to 3 by N)
        (From 3 to 4 by BV)
        (From 4 to 5 by ADV)
        (From 4 to 5 by |#|)
        (From 5 to 6 by DET)
        (From 5 to 7 by DET)
        (From 5 to 8 by |#|)
        (From 6 to 7 by ADJ)
        (From 6 to 6 by MOD)
        (From 7 to 9 by N)
        (From 8 to 8 by MOD)
        (From 8 to 9 by ADJ)
        (From 9 to 4 by CNJ)
        (From 9 to 1 by CNJ)
        (From 9 to 2 by CNJ)
        (From 9 to 3 by CNJ)
        (From 9 to 6 by CNJ)))
> > > (recognize-next
       9
       '()
       '((Initial (1))
         (Final (9))
         (From 1 to 1 by NP)
         (From 1 to 2 by DET)
         (From 1 to 3 by NP)
         (From 2 to 3 by N)
         (From 3 to 4 by BV)
         (From 4 to 5 by ADV)
         (From 4 to 5 by |#|)
         (From 5 to 6 by DET)
         (From 5 to 7 by DET)
         (From 5 to 8 by |#|)
         (From 6 to 7 by ADJ)
         (From 6 to 6 by MOD)
         (From 7 to 9 by N)
         (From 8 to 8 by MOD)
         (From 8 to 9 by ADJ)
         (From 9 to 4 by CNJ)
         (From 9 to 1 by CNJ)
         (From 9 to 2 by CNJ)
         (From 9 to 3 by CNJ)
         (From 9 to 6 by CNJ)))
#t
```

However, when trying to trace something that it is not on the network, trace has a strange behavior. For instance, when I call:

```
(recognize english-1 '(not defined on the network))
```

The output is '() which is correct. But I expected a more detailed information than:

```
'()
```

I was pretty much in doubt about where to put the command (trace recognize-next). I put it just before the end of recognize-next definition. Not sure if this is the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trace` form modifies a binding itself to insert tracing, but it’s usually not something you want to use directly. Instead, it’s usually easier to use `trace-define`, `trace-lambda`, or `trace-let`. Remove your direct use of `(trace recognize-next)`, and replace your definition of `recognize-next` with one that uses `trace-define`:

```
(trace-define (recognize-next node tape network)
  ...)
```

This should make traces work as intended.

Comment: thanks! It worked fine. There is another thing which I cannot understand. Since kim is on my abbreviations definition, why calling (recognize english-1 '(kim)) returns empty '()?

Comment: @fallowzito I admit I have no idea—I didn’t actually read any of your code, just the parts related to `racket/trace`. ;) I’m sure you can figure it out, though: I’d try and play with your functions in the REPL to figure out where they’re going wrong. You might also take a look at the `debug` package, which provides some useful forms to help debug programs.